# How to download text embedding model with R text library?

Tags: r, text, huggingface

I want to use the `r library(text)` for some basic text anaylsis.

A base function of this library is `textembed("some text")` which by defaults downloads a BERT model from huggingface.co, additionally specific models can be specified with a model parameter.

However when I try to do this I get the following error:

```
Error: OSError: Can't load config for 'xlm-roberta-large'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'xlm-roberta-large' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

My R project using GIT is launched from a local folder. Within this folder no config.json or other directory exists. On my user folder structure a .cache folder exists with a hugginface folder but no contents.

This was tried on Windows 10 with R version 4.2.3

Update:
From the console I can see that R downloads a lot of files to my local appdata:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
[nltk_data]     C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
```

However this seems to be the incorrect target destination as it will not be found by R.